# Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matMenu"

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

With the new update of Angular Material and its [breaking changes](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta11-carapace-parapet-2017-09-21), I can no longer use my `<md-menu>` components. It was working when I imported MaterialModule, but now when importing MatMenuModule or MdMenuModule the following error is generated:

```
compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matMenu" ("
</mat-toolbar>
  <mat-menu xPosition="after" [ERROR ->]#wordListMenu="matMenu" 
): 
ng:///NavbarModule/NavbarComponent.html@38:28
```

I follow the guide and API at the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api), but the syntax seems to have changed? I've tried both `#wordListMenu="matMenu"`and `#wordListMenu="mdMenu"` and the error persist.

My html file (relevant parts) is :

```
<button mat-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="wordListMenu" [ngClass]="{'active' 
  : isActive(['/wordlist'])}">
  Word Lists
</button>
<mat-menu xPosition="after" #wordListMenu="matMenu" 
  [overlapTrigger]="false">
  //Content of menu
</mat-menu>
```

My Module is:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {NavbarComponent} from 'app/navbar/navbar.component';
import { MdTooltipModule, MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MdTooltipModule,
    MatMenuModule
  ],
  declarations: [NavbarComponent],
  exports: [NavbarComponent]
})
export class NavbarModule { }
```

Is there something I am missing? Why doesn't the compiler recognize matMenu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with your angular version. Update your angular version to `4.4.3` or greater. Material `2.0.0-beta.11` depends on `4.4.3` or greater. From the [**CHANGELOG**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta11-carapace-parapet-2017-09-21) documentation:

> **Breaking changes** 
>   Angular Material now requires Angular 4.4.3 or greater

Link to [**working demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-beta-u5odez?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: I've tried this and the result is the same, furthermore should both ways work according to the documentation.

Comment: see my answer update. You need to upgrade angular version to >= `4.4.3`

Comment: I've tried changing all `mat->md` and `Mat->Md` as per your answer.  But I get the same error. Maybe not clear but the webpack compiles but the error shows in console in chrome.

Comment: Your angular version is the problem. Upgrade to `4.4.3`. See the demo I linked.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, worked after upgrading to 4.4.3

Comment: The Upgrade did help. But I get other error when running: `ng test --sm=false`: `Error: The "mat-" prefix cannot be used in ng-material v1 compatibility mode. It was used on an "mat-sidenav-container" element.`

I did add `MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE ` as mentioned here: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-prefix-updater) 

Any idea please?

Comment: @k.vincent check the modules that you have imported. The prefix needs to be `Mat` instead of `Md` i.e. `MatSidenavModule`

Comment: @Faisal: I have already done in the whole application - using: `mat-switcher -p path/to/project/tsconfig.json`. Therefore I'am already using: `mat-` instead of: `md-`

Comment: have you provided the `MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE` in the module where your are using `MatSidenavModule` ?

Comment: Yes. `import { MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE } from '@angular/material'; @NgModule({ providers: [
        ...,
        { provide: MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE, useValue: true }
    ]}) export class AppModule { }`

Comment: @k.vincent please follow this link: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6988

Comment: Well, I did. But I just can't find the fix/solution.

Comment: @Faisal: My Bad. Fixed now. I had another custom module used instead of the deprecated `MaterialModule` where I import only the set of components used in the application. There I forgot to add: `MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE `. 
[Clarification on MaterialModule deprecation(https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3991)

Answer (score 2):

If you want add matMenu in html you need to add directive in appmodule.ts
as example..

```
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';

imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 MatMenuModule
]
```

Comment: it's `from '@angular/material/menu';` not `from '@angular/material';`