# mdMenu doesn't work in angular material version: 2.0.0-beta.11

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

What's wrong with this code:

```
<button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
  <button md-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</md-menu>
```

I got error:

> Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to
>   "mdMenu" ("
>
> Menu ]#menu="mdMenu">   Item 1
>   Item 2 "):
>   ng:///UserModule/UserRegistrationComponent.html@113:9

**EDIT: 1**

Also I try this:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

I got this error:

> Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to
>   "matMenu" ("
>
> Menu ]#menu="matMenu">   Item 1
>   Item 2 "):
>   ng:///UserModule/UserRegistrationComponent.html@113:10

**EDIT: 2**

My imports:

```
import {
  MatMenuModule,
  MatButtonModule
} from '@angular/material';
```

**EDIT: 3**

My `user.module`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';
import { UserRoutingModule } from './user-routing.module';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

// material
import {
  MatCardModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatCheckboxModule
} from '@angular/material';

import { UserComponent } from './user.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './user-profile/user-profile.component';
import {
  UserRegistrationComponent
} from './user-registration/user-registration.component';
import {
  UserRestorePasswordComponent
} from './user-restore-password/user-restore-password.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    UserRoutingModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    UserComponent,
    UserProfileComponent,
    UserRegistrationComponent,
    UserRestorePasswordComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    UserService
  ]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

this is my `user.registration.component.html`:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor] = "menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu = "matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: Did you include the MdMenuModule?

Comment: @pzaenger: yes i did

Comment: Hoe are you importing the material modules? And ehat is your angular version?

Comment: @Faisal: I imported material modules, and angular version is 4.3.6

Comment: Please update your version to 4.4.3 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46403948/1791913

Comment: Ok, thanks so much...

Comment: @Faisal: Dear friend thank you very so much. It helped me can You provide Your answer...

Comment: ...so I can check it as right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your angular version. Update your angular version to `4.4.3` or greater. Material `2.0.0-beta.11` depends on `4.4.3` or greater. From the [**CHANGELOG**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta11-carapace-parapet-2017-09-21) documentation:

> **Breaking changes** 
>   Angular Material now requires Angular 4.4.3 or greater

Link to [**working demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-beta-u5odez?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).